# Aregexec in R not extracting the string it's supposed to find

Tags: r, full-text-search

I've had pretty good experience witht the command "aregexec" for searching a string.

For example, I can adjust the tolerance by changing the parameters in "max".
By allowing 1 substitution, no insertion or deletion, I can extract "abcde" from "123accdefg"

```
srch<-aregexec("abcde", "123accdefg", max = list(sub=1,del=0,ins=0), ignore.case = TRUE) 
srch

> srch
[[1]]
[1] 4
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
```

Previously, I've worked with parameters like, max = list(sub=30,del=0,ins=0), and it worked fine. Today I had a moderately complicated task for it but it failed. The following 2 strings are of the same length with 3 substitutions.

```
srch<-aregexec("CAGACGCCCCCAAAA", "CAGACCCCTCCAAGA", max = list(sub=8,del=0,ins=0), ignore.case = TRUE) 
srch
```

I simplified the question by showing the probmatic part. I allowed 8 substitutions which is more than sufficient. But still the aregexec returned nothing.

Instead, if I simplify the task a bit more, like removing the last two characters, it worked.

```
srch<-aregexec("CAGACGCCCCCAA", "CAGACCCCTCCAA", max = list(sub=8,del=0,ins=0), ignore.case = TRUE) 
srch
```

Thank you for you time. I seek for an alternative. Also an explanation would be even better.

Field

Answer (score 1):

The manual of `agrep` says: *If ‘cost’ is not given, ‘all’ defaults to 10%*, so you have to give also a value for `all`:

```
aregexec("CAGACGCCCCCAAAA", "CAGACCCCTCCAAGA",
         max.distance = list(all=3,sub=3,del=0,ins=0), ignore.case = TRUE) 
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#attr(,"match.length")
#[1] 15
```

Comment: Sir. Thank you so much. I read some thread using "max" instead "max.distance" and learned by experimentation. Now your explanation makes perfect sence.